# Order the x axis of a plot according to the same order of the x axis in a plot of another dataframe

Tags: r

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,4,7),
             b=c(3, 5, 6),
             c=c(1, 1, 4),
             d=c(2 ,6 ,3))

df2<-data.frame(id=c("a","b","b","c","c","c","d","d"),
            var=c(12,20,15,18,10,30,5,8))

mediorder <- with(df2, reorder(id, -var, median))

boxplot(var~mediorder, data = df2)

#boxplot of df1 in order "c,b,a,d"
boxplot(df1) # ??
```

Hi,
I have the above two dataframes. For df2 I have ordered the x-axis with id's according to the median values. I would like to make a boxplot of df1 with the x-axis in the same order as the order of df2 (c, b, a, d). My real data set is too large to order them manually.
any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fc = levels(as.factor(mediorder))
ndf1= df1[, order(fc)]
boxplot(ndf1)
```