# How to match an ordered list (e.g., levels(as.factor(x)) ) to another dataframe in which only some columns match?

Tags: r

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,4,7),
              b=c(3, 5, 6),
              c=c(1, 1, 4),
              d=c(2 ,6 ,3))
df2<-data.frame(id=c("a","f","f","b","b","c","c","c","d","d"),
            var=c(12,20,15,18,10,30,5,8,5,5))

mediorder <- with(df2, reorder(id, -var, median))
boxplot(var~mediorder, data = df2)

fc = levels(as.factor(mediorder))
ndf1= df1[, order(fc)] #error here
boxplot(ndf1)
```

Hello,
as an extension to the question here: ([Order the x axis of a plot according to the same order of the x axis in a plot of another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859232/order-the-x-axis-of-a-plot-according-to-the-same-order-of-the-x-axis-in-a-plot-o))

I am trying to make a boxplot of df1 with the x-axis in the same order as the x axis in the plot of df2. However, df2 has an extra id that is non-existent in df1, and using the reordered list causes an error.

Is there a way to match the reordered list with only the columns present in df1 so that the error doesn't occur? The resulting boxplot would then be ordered "b,a,c,d"

Thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this `ndf1= df1[,intersect(fc, colnames(df1))]`

Comment: @JosephWood, That does seem to be what I'm looking for. Thanks :)