# How to add a trendline to a boxplot of counts(y axis) and ids(x axis) when x axis is ordered

Tags: r

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,4,7),
              b=c(3, 5, 6),
              c=c(1, 1, 4),
              d=c(2 ,6 ,3))
df2<-data.frame(id=c("a","f","f","b","b","c","c","c","d","d"),
            var=c(12,20,15,18,10,30,5,8,5,5))

mediorder <- with(df2, reorder(id, -var, median))
boxplot(var~mediorder, data = df2)

fc = levels(as.factor(mediorder))
ndf1= df1[,intersect(fc, colnames(df1))]

ln<-lm( #confused here

boxplot(ndf1) 
abline(ln)
```

I have the above boxplot (ndf1) with an x-axis ordered according to medians from another data frame, and I would like to add a trendline to it.

I am confused since it doesn't have an x and y variable to refer to, just columns with counts. Also the ordering is causing me problems.

EDITED for clarification...
I am building on the question here: [How to match an ordered list (e.g., levels(as.factor(x)) ) to another dataframe in which only some columns match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891868/how-to-match-an-ordered-list-e-g-levelsas-factorx-to-another-dataframe)

All I would like to do is fit a trend line to ndf1

Comment: your question is very confusing. You should clarify it. For instance, the factor "a" has only one value (12) so as "d".

Comment: It is not important as its only an example.

Comment: Well, I think it's not the correct example since you are making a boxplot with one value.

Comment: Thats ok. It simply tells me that value a and d have no variation. You can change the dataframe if you'd like to add more variation, if has no bearing on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do. It's fairly easy using ggplot2. However, your data/question are a bit confusing e.g. Some factors (a,d) have one data point only. Is this what you want?

```
df2$id <- factor(df2$id , levels = levels(mediorder))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = id, y = var)) +  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(group = 1), se = F)
```

[image]

Comment: the trend line should be fit to nfd1

Comment: @joey5, are you saying that the regression line should come from a different data frame that contains different factors to what you have in the box plot data? What is grp?

Comment: Sorry. grp was just from example code i was using to match to my data.

Comment: Where the regression line would come from is sort of my question. I would like to plot df1 with the x axis in the same order as they are ordered in boxplot(df2), which I have done, (ndf1). Now I would like to fit a line to ndf1. As you can see it is confusing (at least so far) since the line depends on the values in df1 and also the order that it is given.